# Como pegar dois atributos de uma mesma classe HTML com JSOUP - JAVA

Tags: java, html, jsoup

To pegando conteúdo de uma página HTML, to selecionando o conteúdo por uma classe específica, mas no caso essa classe tem conteúdo com **a href** e **span**, eu só consigo pegar um só.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.sinonimos.com.br/"+texto+"/" ).get();   
Elements classHTML = doc.getElementsByClass("sinonimos").select("a[href]");
```

De que forma eu filtraria para conseguir pegar o **span** também?

Comment: Não fica claro a informação que você quer pegar. Dê um exemplo do elemento e do que você deseja isolar do mesmo (nos dois casos)

Comment: Consegui resolver.
     Elements classHTML = doc.getElementsByClass("sinonimos").select("a[href],span");

Só usei o "," para usar mais de um atributo.

Comment: Seria interessante colocar uma resposta explicando o que fez.